# Transpile ES7 to ES6 for modern browsers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, babeljs, transpiler

I have a react application written in es6/7 which I am happily transpiling using babel to es5 to be compatible with all browsers.

This got me wondering...

Is it possible to create a js bundle transpiled to es6 which then could be served by say nginx if it is a modern browser? This should save on file size and possibly execution time.

Comment: Sure, why wouldn't it be possible?

Comment: I have searched google for the last one hour and cannot find anything that could do it. I wondered if anyone else did it and how.

Comment: What do you mean by "anything"? You'll have to do it manually - transpile your code to different targets and configure nginx to save different versions of your website depending on browser and its version.

Comment: I was searching for how to transpile to es6, I should have been looking to transpiling to browser targets. That is why I couldn't find anything. Thank I know what I am doing now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Babels [env](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/) preset to create multiple versions of your bundles that provide various levels of browser compatibility.

For example, this *.babelrc* will create a bundle that is compatible with Firefox version 50 and upward:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["Firefox > 50"]
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

Without any parameters, the *env* plugin will create a bundle that works on a wide range of browsers, which probably will be much bigger than one built specifically for a modern browser like Firefox:

```
{
  "presets": ["env"]
}
```

The *env* preset uses [browserslist](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist) to specify the browsers that Babel should use as transpilation target. Browserslist features a query language that lets you specify browsers by type, platform, version, usage statistics, etc. Check out their documentation to figure out which queries to use for your specific audience.

You can try out the browserslist queries on the command line like this:

```
npx browserslist "> 10%, last 3 versions"
```

This gives you a list of the last 3 versions of browsers whose usage is higher than 10%.

Once you've figured out which browserslist queries work for you to create a big bundle for maximum browser compatibility and a slimmer one for modern browsers, you can use the [ngx_http_browser_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_browser_module.html) to serve the bundle depending on the user agent of the incoming request.